# Axis2: Disable MustUnderstand Header Check

Tags: java, web-services, soap, header, apache-axis

I'm writing a web service using the Axis2 framework. The service is going to act as a proxy in a DMZ. It is really just a relay to the real service which is in our local lan.

The service uses headers which have the mustUnderstand flag set. But since the proxy service is rather simple, it cannot understand these headers, it is just supposed to relay the request into our lan, where all headers can be processed.

The problem is, that Axis2 checks the headers and throws a fault, since the module  which normally reads and understands the header is not present.

Is there a way to configure Axis2 so, that it does ignore the mustUnderstand flag?

Alternatively a way to handle that from code would be apreciated too.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We had to do something similar, so this should get you close to what you want.

What you need is an `org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler`

In the `Invoke(MessageContext msgContext)` function, you can do something like this

```
SOAPHeader header = msgContext.getEnvelope().getHeader();
if( header != null )
{
    Iterator<?> blocks = soapHeader.examineAllHeaderBlocks();
    while( blocks.hasNext() )
    {
        SOAPHeaderBlock block = (SOAPHeaderBlock)blocks.next();
        if( ... some check to see if this is one of your headers ... )
            block.setProcessed();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

What i did, based on the response of @karoberts is:

- Modify the "Inflow" section in axis2.xml and add the following

  ```
  <phase name="PreDispatch">
      <handler name="WSQinHandler"
               class="com.qin.utils.post.WSQinHandler"/>
  </phase>
  ```
- Create a new class with the name of the handler. the magic comes with SOAPBlock object that have the setMustUnderstand. When this method is set to false, Axis don't check the header.

  ```
  package com.qin.utils.post;

  import java.util.Iterator;
  import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPEnvelope;
  import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPHeader;
  import org.apache.axiom.soap.SOAPHeaderBlock;
  import org.apache.axis2.AxisFault;
  import org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext;
  import org.apache.axis2.handlers.AbstractHandler;

  public class WSQinHandler extends AbstractHandler {

      @Override
      public InvocationResponse invoke(MessageContext ctx) throws AxisFault {

          SOAPEnvelope envelop = (SOAPEnvelope) ctx.getEnvelope(); 
          SOAPHeader header = envelop.getHeader();
          if( header != null )
          {
              Iterator<?> blocks = header.examineAllHeaderBlocks();
              while( blocks.hasNext() )
              {
                  SOAPHeaderBlock block = (SOAPHeaderBlock)blocks.next();
                  block.setMustUnderstand(false);
              }
          }
          return InvocationResponse.CONTINUE;
      }

  }
  ```